# how to make obsidian without lava in minecraft pocket edition ipad/tablet

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

how do we make obsidian in minecraft without lava? If there is another way, then please tell me. I have tried to find some, but no luck for me. If you know a seed or another way to make please tell.

Comment: search your question before asking your question

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jft89B8Z4dA. This is the first result for googling "how to get obsidian in Minecraft PE"

Comment: Many of your questions have been downvoted due to having zero punctuation, and not searching beforehand.  We don't mind helping people that have problems, but we *do* require you to put some effort into helping yourself, and then spending time making yourself understood.  If you want to have a good reception here at Arqade, follow those simple rules, and you'll be getting answers and being welcomed in no time.  In short, at least search Arqade for if your question has been asked, and if not, spend some time ensuring you have both spelling and punctuation.

Comment: As I said in your previous question, *tell us how it's not a duplicate*.  You're free to challenge a duplicate, but it's up to you to tell us how it's not.  So far, all you've done is say, "It's not a duplicate at all".  You need to expand on that, and tell us how it isn't.

Comment: because i dont search the answer to my question before writing it thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without lava it is **not** possible to make obsidian. For your reference, here are a few lava seeds:

- Nyan
- free me!
- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
- life360

Don't forget the capital letters, if any in the seed. Hope this helps!